# Change blender navigation to keyboard? something like unreal?

Tags: navigation

is it possible to change blender's navigation to something like unreal? via keyboard

Does anyone know if there is a way (code, addon, preferences, etc.) to add interface navigation to Blender from other software? I really like Unreal Engine's navigation and wonder if there is any way to replicate that in Blender's interface.

[Adding Other Software's Interface Navigation to Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/276623/adding-other-softwares-interface-navigation-to-blender)

Comment: AFAIK it's all in the keymap settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate the scene using keyboard. Try Fly or Walk navigation from View -> Navigation menu in 3d Viewport:

[image]

You can right click them in the menu and assign a shortcut to activate more easily. There are also some settings for them in the preferences:

[image]